# javascript error message not showing on ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

The error message when i click on the search button without capturing anything is showing on all browsers and not showing on IE9. How do i fix this?`

```js
function sendData() {
  $("#searchError").css("visibility", "hidden");
  var id = $('#number').val();
  errorMessage = "";
  if (id == null || id == "") errorMessage = "Please enter a valid number";
  else if (id.length < 13) errorMessage = "Please enter a valid number";


  if (errorMessage.length > 0) {
    $("#searchError").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#searchErrorText").text(errorMessage);
    $("#number").focus();
    return "false";
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="bob-btn-info" onclick="sendData()">Search</button>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Allways record error console messages"

Load you website, then press f12 to display the Developer tool.. any errors that have occurred will be listed in the Developer tool console.

Comment: @fulufhelomudau reload the page again

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to have boolean value instead of string:

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, you have to add an id to the button and use the following code:

```js
$( "#idForButton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#nameForInputBox" ).focus();
});
```